# How to stop mediaPlayback Foreground Service when notification is swiped away on Android 14?

Tags: android, foreground-service, foregroundnotification, android-14

The music is played on `mediaPlayback` type Foreground Service.

When notification for Foreground Service is swiped away, the music keeps playing on Android 14 devices. This is because of the changes to non-dismissible notifications that is introduced in Android 14:

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/behavior-changes-all#non-dismissable-notifications

How can I stop the foreground service when its notification is swiped away on Android 14?

Comment: Check out the NotificationCompat.Builder.setDeleteIntent